# Appending multiple buttons to a Bootstrap search form

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap, appending more than one button to a `.form-search` rounds the right corners of both appended buttons.

HTML:

```
<form class="form-search">
  <div class="input-append">
    <input type="text" class="span2 search-query">
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Quick</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Full</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/aFYcM/3/

How can I adjust the CSS so that only the last button gets the rounded corners and the middle button is "square"?

---

Just for context, I can append multiple buttons to an input, and only the right-most button gets the rounded corners:

```
<div class="alert alert-success">
    Regular input can append two buttons such that the middle button ("Quick") does not have rounded corners:<br />
    <form>
        <div class="input-append">
          <input type="text" class="span2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Quick</button>
            <a href="somewhere.html" class="btn">Full</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/aFYcM/4/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I created a [corresponding issue with Bootstrap](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/6415), but it was closed ("We don't support that, and will likely remove the ability to do multiple buttons in 3.0." -mdo). So I crafted my own CSS to fix the issue (please see http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/aFYcM/34/).

The key was to redefine (to 0) the border-radius declarations in the `.form-search .input-append .fixed-btn`* styles, and do the same for `.prepend`. Then declare the correct border-radius specifications using the `:last-child` selector.

```
.form-search .input-append .fixed-btn, .form-search .input-prepend .fixed-btn {
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}

.form-search .input-append .btn:last-child {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 14px 14px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 14px 14px 0;
    border-radius: 0 14px 14px 0;
}
```

*--Please note I created `.fixed-btn` for the fiddle because I am including the Bootstrap assets from a CDN (I can't edit the CDN's CSS with my changes). For those who are inclined, you can add these lines to your style.less file to get the corrections into the resulting CSS:

```
.navbar-search .input-prepend .btn, .navbar-search .input-append .btn {
    margin-left: -1px;
    .border-radius(0 0 0 0);
}
.navbar-search .input-append .search-query {
    .border-radius(14px 0 0 14px);
}
.navbar-search .input-append .btn:last-child {
    .border-radius(0 14px 14px 0);
}
```